# Finding all the groups of non adjacent items (with a given number) from binary adjacency matrix

Tags: matrix

I have a square adjacency matrix $S$ of size $12\times 12$.

```
matrix = {
    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
    {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
    {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
    {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}
};
matrix // TeXForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$S$ has the following properties:

- The elements of $S$ are $0$s and $1$s.
- $S$ is symmetric; $S_{i,j}=S_{j,i}$.
- if item $i$ is adjacent to item $j$ then $S_{i,j}=S_{j,i}=1$

I want to find the all the combinations with $X$ number of non-adjacent elements.

$X$ can be 3, 4, 5, etc.

Comment: Your matrix is not symmetric

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to "find the all the combinations" with $X$ number of non adjacent elements?

Comment: @CarlWoll, I know, I just generated this binary matrix. In fact, I am just looking for some standard method to find all the combinations of non-adjacent elements (vertices) with 3 vertices.

Comment: @jjc385, I am just looking for some standard method to find all the combinations of non-adjacent elements (vertices) with 3 vertices. For example, {1, 3, 5}, {2 6 9}, ... are the sets (3 components) of non-adjacent components (vertices)

Comment: @dipaknarayanan Do you disagree that your adjacency matrix should be symmetric?

Comment: @jjc385, no no, I am disagreeing. It must be a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Good!  Could you edit the question so that the matrix is symmetric?  I think this would alleviate some confusion.  While you're at it, it would be great if you'd add your clarifications about what you're looking for -- your comment to me above is a nice start, but it's most helpful if you an put the information directly into the question.

Comment: @jjc385, I think I now have a symmetric matrix

Comment: @dipaknarayanan I am missing a clear definition of what you mean by "a list with nonadjacent elements". As Mathematician, I tend to read it as "a list of pairwise nonadjacent elements". Is this the definition that you have in mind?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, lets say.. I have 12 transmitters. At any point of time, only three transmitters can be turned on. The adjacent transmitters cannot be turned on as they will interfere each other. I just want all the possible combinations. The adjacency matrix says which transmitters are adjacent to which transmitters...

Comment: @dipaknarayanan You did not answer my question. The adjacency matrix tells us whether _two_ vertices are adjacent. But that leaves room for interpretation what it means for a list of $n>2$ elements to be "nonadjacent". From the transmitter setup, I deduce that you actually mean "pairwise nonadjacent". I think that Carl's post provides a complete answer in this case.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

As @kglr points out, using [`FindIndependentVertexSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentVertexSet) in the way I suggested can miss out on some independent vertex sets. These missing independent vertex sets are actually subsets of a larger independent vertex set. In this case:

```
FindIndependentVertexSet[
    AdjacencyGraph @ matrix,
    {4},
    All
]
```

> {{2, 4, 7, 9}}

So, the missing 3-sets are just the 4 possible length 3 subsets of {2, 4, 7, 9}.

So, to find all possible independent 3-sets using [`FindIndependentVertexSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindIndependentVertexSet), one should instead use:

```
all = FindIndependentVertexSet[AdjacencyGraph@matrix, {3, Infinity}, All]
```

> {{2, 4, 7, 9}, {8, 11, 12}, {2, 8, 12}, {2, 4, 12}, {3, 11, 12}, {3, 9, 
>     11}, {3, 5, 10}, {3, 5, 9}, {1, 11, 12}, {7, 9, 11}, {7, 8, 11}, {4, 7, 
>     10}, {5, 7, 10}, {5, 7, 9}, {5, 7, 8}, {2, 7, 8}, {2, 6, 7}}

Then, replace all vertex sets with more than 3 elements with all of the length 3 subsets:

```
Union @ Catenate @ Map[Subsets[#, {3}]&] @ all
```

> {{1, 11, 12}, {2, 4, 7}, {2, 4, 9}, {2, 4, 12}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 7, 
>     8}, {2, 7, 9}, {2, 8, 12}, {3, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 10}, {3, 9, 11}, {3, 
>     11, 12}, {4, 7, 9}, {4, 7, 10}, {5, 7, 8}, {5, 7, 9}, {5, 7, 
>     10}, {7, 8, 11}, {7, 9, 11}, {8, 11, 12}}

**Original answer**

I think you're looking for independent vertex sets:

```
FindIndependentVertexSet[
    AdjacencyGraph @ matrix,
    {3},
    All
]
```

> {{8, 11, 12}, {2, 8, 12}, {2, 4, 12}, {3, 11, 12}, {3, 9, 11}, {3, 5, 10}, {3,
>      5, 9}, {1, 11, 12}, {7, 9, 11}, {7, 8, 11}, {4, 7, 10}, {5, 7, 10}, {5, 7, 
>     9}, {5, 7, 8}, {2, 7, 8}, {2, 6, 7}}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I want all the possible groups (of 3 elements) with non-adjacent elements. For example,  group 1= {1 3 5} means 1st, 3rd and 5th vertices are non-adjacent. There can be multiple such groups. I just need all these groups. {1 3 9} can also be such a group,

Comment: @dipaknarayanan Could you give examples of 3 vertices that don't meet the non-adjacent list criteria as well? Are there 12 vertices? I don't understand why {1, 3, 5} meets your non-adjacent elements criteria.

Comment: I think I could not explain the point well. It all depends how we number the vertices.  if the vertices 1 3 and 5 are non-adjacent, it can be  a set.

Comment: Ah, okay. I am off then.